# Average estimated beta does not equal to true beta by sim.survdata

Tags: survival, simulation, cox-model

I recently use the R "sim.survdata" function in "coxed" package to simulate survival data. I did 2k simulations with one covariate and coefficient = 1. Each time I fitted a Cox regression and recorded the estimated beta and 95% CI. However the mean(betahat) doesn't equal to 1, and CIs do not cover 1 at 95% times. Please see the codes I used below. I wonder the reasons, any input is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

```
bhat=NULL
lb=NULL
ub=NULL
for(i in 1:2000){
set.seed(20110312+i)
simdata <- sim.survdata(N=2633, T=200, xvars=1, censor=.85, num.data.frames = 1, beta = 1)
simdata$data$event=as.numeric(simdata$data$failed)
fit=coxph(Surv(y,event==1)~X,data=simdata$data)
bhat=c(bhat,summary(fit)$coefficients[1])
lb=c(lb,log(summary(fit)$conf.int[3]))
ub=c(ub,log(summary(fit)$conf.int[4]))
}

> mean(bhat)
[1] 0.9408025
> mean(lb<=1 & ub>=1)
[1] 0.904
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see the issue? In each iteration I set the seed to be 20110312+i, where i is changing in each iteration, so is the seed? Besides, I also test ran my codes without setting the seeds and got similar results.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the "I" in the code for a "1".

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you set `fixed.hazard = TRUE` in the function call, instead of the default `FALSE`? I notice in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxed/vignettes/simulating_survival_data.html#attributes-of-a-simulation) that the values of `beta` specified in a simulation don't agree with the Cox coefficients in a model fitted to the simulated data. I wonder whether that has to do with the randomness in baseline hazards among simulated cases with the default `fixed.hazard = FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you EdM. I haven't tried ```fixed.hazard = TRUE``` yet, but I just read this link: https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/when-is-censoring-too-high/1534, in which it wrote something about too high censoring rate may lead to biased analytical results. I think it may cause my problem, as I set up ```censoring = 0.85``` which is way too high. (?)  I tried a low censoring rate (```censor = 0.1```) and did the simulation again, and so far it looked more right to me.

Comment: If you found that the high censoring was the source of the problem, or if `fixed.hazard =TRUE` helps, please post that work as an answer to this question. It's OK to post answers to your own questions here. That would be a service to others who come to this site with a similar question.